# What can be excluded from source control in SPT 2010 solution (VS 2010)?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, solution-package

Besides the usual bin and obj folders, what else can be excluded from source control in the Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint solution I've built?

I'm particularly interested in whether the pkg and pkgobj folders can be excluded. They contain copies of files I created but the pkgobj folder contains a subfolder called TokenReplaceFolder. If I don't check this in, is my solution likely to blow up when someone checks it out for the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the pkg or the pkgobj folders, they are temporary and used by the packaging routine

Answer (score 2):

I did not check this yet. If it aint in your VS2010 project, it doesn't need to go in your source control. My SP2010 project doesn't have theses files/folders in TFS and it's not an issue for check-out. I've switched VM a couple of times, check-out my projects, build it and deployed without any issue.

To test that you can copy the files in another location, remove all the folders/files you think are unecessary and build it.